# Why are some diacritics not aligned properly on Android?

Tags: android

In my Android application, I want to display some text that contains Unicode combining diacritical marks (see [details in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)).  I specifically need to combine four marks (codes 0300, 0301, 0302, and 030C) with Cyrillic characters.

These combinations look fine in the text editor on my Linux desktop, but not in my application.

- In TextViews, the grave accent mark (0300) and the acute accent mark (0301) combine fine, but other two marks appear *near* the main character, but not *above* it, like expected, so there is an empty space at the right of the character, and the diacritics is above it, shifted to the right from its proper place.
- On buttons, all four marks are displayed shifted to the right.

Here is a picture of a sample TextView.  The first mark is shifted and the second one is fine.

[image]

How to fix that?  Is that a problem of a font or of the system rendering?